# Using a jQuery custom scrollbar autoscrolls my body

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, autoscroll

My page consists of an Accordion (from Primefaces) with 9 categories.
In one category I have a table with a width bigger than my screen width.
I decided to use a better looking horizontal scrollbar than the default, so I searched and found a jQuery scrollbar called Malihu Scrollbar

http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/complete_examples.html

After some research, I successfully managed to use it in the specific accordion tab as a horizontal scrollbar. The problem is that when I leave the specific tab expanded, **my whole body cannot scroll down to bottom**, but instead it automatically scrolls some pixels above the bottom (I lose about one accordion tab header), either when I scroll using mouse wheel or when I scroll using the scrollbar of my whole body (I want to point out here that the scrollbar of the whole body is not a custom scrollbar but a common one). If the tab with the custom scrollbar is not expanded, my page works great.

This is my accordion scrolled to the bottom:
[image: Accordion scrolled to the bottom]

And this is the most I can scroll my page down, when the accordion tab with the custom scrollbar is expanded:
[image: Accordion with autoscroll problem]

As you can see the body is not fully scrolled to the bottom. **If I try to scroll it to the bottom it goes right up to this position** until I collapse the tab which is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

First of all the problem was in an option of Malihu Scrollbars called **autoExpandHorizontalScroll**. I am not sure what this option exactly does but it is necessary. If this option is not on, the scrollbar doesn't appear when I put my table in the accordion. When I put my table outside the accordion the scrollbar works fine even with autoExpandHorizontalScroll set off. My code in XHTML is:

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(".horizontalScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar({
                scrollButtons:{ enable:false },
                horizontalScroll:true,
                advanced:{autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true}
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

As I said before, when I put my table outside the accordion the scrollbar appears anyway. The difference is that when autoExpandHorizontalScroll is true I get the autoscroll problem (described in the original post), but when I set it to false, my body stops this annoying autoscrolling. So I decided to take a look at Malihu's code to see what this option does.

autoExpandHorizontalScroll appears in two functions: `init:function(options)`, and `update:function()` and it does just the following in both cases:

```
mCSB_container.css({"position":"absolute","width":"auto"}).wrap("<div class='mCSB_h_wrapper' style='position:relative; left:0; width:999999px;' />").css({"width":mCSB_container.outerWidth(),"position":"relative"}).unwrap();
```

I don't know what the idea here is, but after some experimenting with it, **I just removed the part that is in `init:function(options)` (comment it on line 214)** and left the part that is in the update function. After this, the scrollbar works perfectly in the accordion and no autoscroll problem is bothering me anymore.

By the way: Sorry for posting a so specific question. I hope somebody finds it useful